# Access <html> styles to hide overflow in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In one of my components I have a morph button and I want to hide `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` while it's active. How can I access style properties of -tag which is inside my index.html file and am I overally able to do it with the help of Angular 2 or I have to just access it with javascript functions like document.getElement....style.overflowY? Somehow it feels wrong while building Angular 2 app.

Comment: Just access with JS. Angular2 doesn't provide anything to access HTML outside the root component except the title tag in head.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank's for your answer, will do it then.